# How to use if directive in apache2.4 to deny all excepts some routes

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm working in a configuration for an API rest, and I want to deny all the routes except the use by the API.

I'm trying to make this
Allow all the query_string with match with /rest or /rest/* in it.
Deny the rest of the routes.

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /rest/">
  Require all granted
</If>
<Else>
  Require all denied
</Else>
```

I only get denied for all the routes.

Comment: Your configuration looks correct. I suggest that you try turning on debug logging to figure out why your regexp doesn't match the query string. (You do this by changing the usual `LogLevel warn` to `LogLevel debug` in your main config file.)

Answer (score -1):

You can to deny all in your main Directory, and allow all in the rest location.

Something like this:

```
 <Directory /path/to/your/docroot>
   Require all denied
   ...
 </Directory>
 ...
 <LocationMatch "^/rest">
   Require all granted
 </LocationMatch>
```

Comment: That would work if the question was about locations - but it's about the query string, i.e. the part that comes after a `?` in the URI.

Comment: The questions says "deny all excepts some routes". The sample code is trying to do this checking the query_param but IMHO is a wrong approach (probably because of a clean URL functionality). So, the proposed answer denies all routes but not the ones beginning with "/rest".